# Possible to execute functions on API?

Tags: c#, php, node.js, http, xamarin

I started making a app with C#(Xamarin) and now I want to send data fron C# to a PHP or node.js server.

I want to use http(System.Net.Http) to make a simple login, can I run a method directly or do I have to send a json package and recieve it back?

If there are better methods pleas tell me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the best way is to send a POST request using .Net.Http and receive it on your server. Then return a json array with the results for example:

```
...Login logic...
$result = ['status' => 'success', 'report' => 'Your data is correct'];  

die(json_encode($return));
```

You can parse that JSON using libs from C#.

Conclusion: For me the best and secure way is to encript your POST data, send to server then return json response.

Comment: Thx and how would in this case a POST request in C# look like?

Comment: Please read this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36458551/send-http-post-request-in-xamarin-forms-c-sharp